# Getting distance between farLat, farLng and nearLat, nearLng

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am getting far and near LatLng as below :

```
mFarLeft = mMapView.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().farLeft;
mFarRight = mMapView.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().farRight;
mNearLeft = mMapView.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().nearLeft;
mNearRight = mMapView.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().nearRight;
```

Now, How can I calculate the distance between this far and near points?
Is there any method available to get distance in KM and Feet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields `farLeft`, `farRight`, etc. are actually `LatLng` objects, according to the Android [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion).  However, there is a field `latLngBounds` which represents the smallest bounding box including the visible region.  This bounds object itself has two `LatLng` fields for the northeast and southwest corners of the box.  Using the Haversine formula we can compute the distance between the corners of this box.  For example, if you wanted to compute the height of the bounding box we can try:

```
public static double haversine(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);

    double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat / 2),2) + Math.pow(Math.sin(dLon / 2),2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    return 6372.8 * c;   // in kilometers
    // if you want to return feet, then use 6372.8 * 3280.84 instead
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LatLng ne = mMapView.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.northeast;
    LatLng sw = mMapView.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.southwest;
    double latLow = sw.latitude;
    double latHigh = ne.latitude;
    double longitude = sw.longitude;

    // now compute the "height" of the bounding box
    // note that the longitude value is the same
    double height = haversine(latLow, longitude, latHigh, longitude);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a utility library for Maps that can, among other things,

> #### Calculate distances, areas and headings via spherical geometry
>
> Using the spherical geometry utilities in `SphericalUtil`, you can compute distances, areas, and headings based on latitudes and longitudes. Here are some of the methods available in the utility:
>
> - `computeDistanceBetween()` – Returns the distance, in meters, between two latitude/longitude coordinates.
> - `computeHeading()` – Returns the bearing, in degrees, between two latitude/longitude coordinates.
> - `computeArea()` – Returns the area, in square meters, of a closed path on the Earth.
> - `interpolate()` – Returns the latitude/longitude coordinates of a point that lies a given fraction of the distance between two given points. You can use this to animate a marker between two points, for example.
>
> Refer to the [reference documentation](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/) for a full list of methods in the utility.

The library is available on maven central.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
}
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/